# Not able to access nested radio component using Appium

Tags: android, react-native, automated-tests, appium

I'm testing a react-native application with Appium when i run tests on Android i can't access a nested Radio component inside a View.

[Appium Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGDwQ.png)

[React Native Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR7Sb.png)

Comment: Hi Pratik, can you improve your question adding more information to help other to understand what you need: i.e, Given this code, when i click... i expect..

Comment: Hey @IvanLynch please find one more image for your reference in the code automation tool such as appium is not able to access <Radio> tag class